# Переменная double в Windows Forms Pascal ABC

Tags: pascalabc.net

Пишу программу по расчету BMI на формах, ранее написал в консольном виде.
Код:

```
uses crt;
var m:integer;
var h,r:double;
begin
  writeln('Вас приветствует программа по расчету BMI(Расчет индека массы тела) в строчку роста в ');
  writeln('метрах введите ваш рост,например: 1,72, а в строку "Масса" введите свой вес.');
  writeln('Например:60. Приятного использования!');
  writeln();
  write('Рост в метрах: ');
  readln(h);
  write('Масса: ');
  readln(m);
  r:= m / (h*h);
  writeln('Ваш BMI равен: ' + r);
  if r <= 15.01 then
    writeln('У вас острый дефицит веса!');
  if (r>15.01) and (r<=20.01) then
    writeln('У вас дефицит веса!'); 
  if (r>20.01) and (r<= 25.01) then
    writeln('У вас нормальный вес!');
  if (r>25.01) and (r<=30.01) then
    writeln('У вас избыточный вес!');
  if r>30.01 then
    writeln('У вас ожирение!');
end.
```

Начал писать эту же программу на Windows Forms, хотел присвоить значение переменной `h` `textBox1`
Код:

```
var a,h,r:double;
begin
  h := textBox1.Text
end;
```

Компилятор выдал ошибку:

> нельзя преобразовать тип real к integer

Как задать `textBox1`. Вещественное, или напишите код программы которой, я хочу на Windows Forms.

Comment: `h := StrToFloat(textBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 1):

Может быть уже поздно, но лучше использовать TryStrToFloat.

С его помощью проще отловить недопустимые данные.

P.S. В PABC.NET типы Real и Double — идентичны.

Answer (score 1):

Логично. У Вас переменная h - типа double (вещественный) и вы пытаетесь присвоить к переменной вещественного типа в качестве значения текст. Я бы удивился если бы компилятор "проглотил" это. В данном случае вам подойдёт преобразование "СтрокаВЧисло":

h := StrToFloat(textBox1.Text); //Если число вещественное

либо

h := StrToInt(textBox1.Text); //Если бы число было бы целочисленным.

И как написал комментатор выше, я так же считаю что правильнее "пробовать" то есть:
TryStrToFloat либо TryStrToInt.

P.S. В вашей программе вместо if я бы использовал case. Но тут, как говорится, каждому своё ;)